# How to create Struts 2 project in Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I want to create a struts 2 project in eclipse. I have downloaded the latest struts distribution. But things always become confusing when i try to create a struts project in ECLIPSE. 
Whenever I create a dynamic web project and add struts libraries to that project, some error or the other pops up.

How do I properly setup an eclipse Struts 2 project ?

To get a simple Hello world page, I did:

1. created a dynamic web project (procollab)
2. added struts 2 jars inside WEB-INF/lib
3. added the same libraries inside project build path
4. set the output folder for the src in WEB-INF/classes
5. created a filter in web.xml to send all requests to org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
6. created a struts.xml in src

Errors I get:

Http 404. I get this for any URL,  for example  http://localhost:8080   or http://localhost:8080/procollab

I have added the project procollab in tomcat server list also in eclipse. but when I access any static resource directly, I get the page. I have the helloworld.jsp in webcontent folder, and when I go to http:localhost:8080/procollab/helloworld.jsp, I get the page correctly.

Have I set up my environment correctly ? Please help

my struts.xml file in WEB-INF/classes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1.7//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.7.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="SayHello">
            <result>/hello.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: Errors tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once the cause is *understood*, the solution is *obvious*. So, if you actually have a hard time in understanding the errors, please edit your question to include the actual errors. Then we'll help explaining them.

Comment: yes I have enlisted the problems I get and the steps I did

Comment: Steps 3 and 4 are by the way unnecessary. `/WEB-INF/lib` is by default already covered by the build path. The output folder is by default already that way. All with thanks to Eclipse.

Comment: Another "by the way": you can also just put `struts.xml` in `src` folder. It will automagically be taken in `/WEB-INF/classes`. No need to move/copy/crazy it around ;) Eclipse does all the nasty work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Http 404. I get this for any URL, for example http://localhost:8080 or http://localhost:8080/procollab

So that's the only problem? Well, a 404 just means that there's no resource on the requested URL. Page Not Found. Simple as that. You need to provide/specify the resource yourself, Eclipse won't do that for you or so. It's the code which you have full in control yourself.

I am not sure what you expect to see at http://localhost:8080, so I'll ignore this part. As to the 404 on http://localhost:8080/procollab, you just need to define a `<welcome-file>` in the `web.xml` and ensure that this is available by either (in)directly by a servlet or filter mapping, or a physical file in `WebContent`. That's all.

If you want to make `helloworld.jsp` the default landing page, you'll need to add the following to the `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/helloworld.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Update**: as per the posted struts config, you thus expect that http://localhost:8080/procollab/SayHello.action is been executed when you access http://localhost:8080/procollab. In this case, you need to configure the `<welcome-file>` as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/SayHello.action</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I have setup a filter for the url pattern  /*    to go via struts filter dispatcher.

Comment: So? Does struts have anything ready on `/*`? Apparently not, as per the 404.

Comment: i have created a struts.xml in WEB-INF/classes and there, i have a package under namespace  /   and an action under it that will bring up a hello world jsp page

Comment: Then you'll need to post more details about the struts config and if any also any inconsistencies in the server startup logs.

Comment: What I have tried to do is 

web.xml -> Filter -> struts.xml -> SayHello.action -> /hello.jsp

Comment: I found the mistake I did. I did a stupid mistake in typing the URL. I should append .action after the action name. I mean instead of giving http://localhost:8080/SayHello, I should type http://localhost:8080/SayHello.action  :) thanks for all your support